# Can Bootbox.confirm work synchronously?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootbox

In an aspx page, there is an asp:linkbutton like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btExit" Text="Exit"
                OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmExit();" 
                EnableViewState="false" 
                OnClick="ExitButtonClick"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And this is the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmExit() {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (confirmed) {
        return confirmed;
    });
}
</script>
```

The problem is that, as far as I know, bootbox.confirm works asynchronously, and ExitButtonClick function on code behind is executed without waiting for the user confirmation.

I found a solution that works, using a hidden button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btExit" Text="Exit"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btExitHidden" onclick="ExitButtonClick" style="display:none;" />
```

And this is the javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btExit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (confirmed) {
            if (confirmed) {
                $("#btExitHidden").click();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My question is if there is a more "beautiful" and "standard" way to work synchronously with a Bootbox.confirm, without using a hidden button.

Comment: `bootbox.confirm` is in no way async, it just has a callback for whenever someone confirms or not, so yes, it can be used synchronously, and you're already doing it.

Comment: @adeneo Umm yes it is async. When you make the call to `bootbox.confirm` it opens the dialog then continues executing. We don't know when the user is going to click one of the buttons that executes the callback. It happens asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom sync bootbox function this way:

```
function ayncBootbox(message, cb = null) { // cb : function
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            bootbox.confirm({
                message: message,
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label: "Yes"
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label: "No"
                    }
                },
                callback: cb ? result => cb(resolve, result) : result => resolve(result)
            })
        })
}
```

then you can call it this way by passing a custom callback if you need to do some extra stuff

```
var result = await ayncBootbox("message", (resolve, result) => resolve(result))
```

Or just

```
var result = await ayncBootbox("message")
```

PS: don't forget to make the caller function as async as well :) and you can extend this code more with reject if needed

Answer (score -2):

My solution

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteReport", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", onclick = String.Format("return ASE.ConfirmAction(this.href, 'Delete {0}?');", item.Name) })
```

```
var ASE = {
    ConfirmAction: function (href, text) {
        bootbox.confirm(text, function (result) {
            if (result)
                window.location = href;
        });

        return false;
    }
}
```